# Ignoring exceptions when using c# selenium webdriverWait wait.untill() function

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2013

In order to check if an Element is exists and clickble  i'm trying to write a boolean method which will wait for the element to be enabled and displyed using C# selenium's webDriverWait as follow:

```
webDriverWait wait = new webDriverWait(driver, timeSpan.fromSeconds(60));

Wait.untill( d => webElement.enabled() && webElement.displayed());
```

In case the above conditions do not happen, I want the method to return 'false'. The problem is that I get exceptions thrown.
How can I ignore exceptions such as noSuchElementException and timeOutException in case they are thrown?
I have tried to use try catch block but it didn't help and exceptions were thrown.

Comment: Can you provide some more specific information as: 1. You want the element to be visible or clickable? 2. Some how have you measured what's the minimum & maximum time the element requires to be visible/clickable?

Comment: Hi, (1)I want the element to be visble and clickble. (2) I want to wait untill 60 seconds.

Comment: I don't know the the exact min and max time since I would like to implement the above code not for specific element. I need to write a method which I can use not for a specific element.

Comment: can you update exactly what type of exception is it throwing?

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException and 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException' occurred in  WebDriver.Support.dll

Comment: You should probably spend a minute and update your code. That looks like a mix of C# and Java with the casing you are using and you've got some spelling mistakes in your methods. Also, take a look at the help topics around formatting code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WebDriverWait` implements `DefaultWait` class that contains `public void IgnoreExceptionTypes(params Type[] exceptionTypes)` method.

You can use this method for defining all the exception types you want to ignore while waiting for element to get enabled before clicking.

For example :

```
WebDriverWait wdw = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
wdw.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException), typeof(ElementNotVisibleException));
```

In the preceding code wait will ignore NoSuchElementException and ElementNotVisibleException exceptions

Comment: Nope.  I'm using this exact code, but it still throws an exception of "No such element, unable to locate element... [etc]..."    Grrrr.....

Comment: Same problem here hence why I am on this thread. I can clearly see the wait instance using the IgnoreExceptionTypes statement while debugging but it doesn't actually ignore them.

Answer (score 2):

If you wait for the element to be clickable, it will also be displayed and enabled. You can simply do

```
public bool IsElementClickable(By locator, int timeOut)
{
    try
    {
        new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(locator));

        return true;
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and it will wait for 60s and click the element once it is found. It still may throw an exception if the element is not found, doesn't become clickable, etc. after the timeout expires.

EDIT:
Wrapped this up in a function based on OPs comment.

Comment: Hi, wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable() method exists in Java, not on c#.

Comment: Not true. I have VS up and typed and formatted that code and it works just fine not to mention I'm using it in the project that I'm working on right now.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. What about the exceptions? Is there any way to ignore them?

Comment: This code automatically ignores them up until the timeout expires. If the element is not found, not clickable, etc. an exception is still going to be thrown. Are you trying to write a function that returns a `bool` if the element is clickable or ?

Comment: Correct, this is what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Updated the code. I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this is working. But still I have a little problam since i'm using Page factory to init my elements as part of using Page object model, so I want to pass the method the element itself and not the By locator.

Comment: You can just pass in the `IWebElement` instead. You should read the docs so you can see how to do this stuff yourself. It's pretty straightforward. https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm

Comment: If you found this (or any) answer helpful, please upvote it. If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: *wait.Until* works pretty weird, IMHO. I cannot make it work even with generic Exception. If element is not present - it's just not caught! Exception happens in Until and caught block is not fired. Using C#, just in case. I think it's because it happens in inner block, *Func<IWebDriver, ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>>*, that should be somehow checked in the first place...

Comment: @Alexander I use `wait.Until()` all the time and it works just fine. If the condition is not met before the time out occurs, it will throw a time out exception. This is how it's designed.

Comment: @JeffC, just to cut long story short, I will show the exception I get: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lp0daw3raio4ook/TimeoutException.png?dl=0 - no matter what i try, i cannot get into catch block. Even if i used other kind of condition or if i use generic exception. It ALWAYS stuck on Until. That's it.

Comment: @JeffC, FindElement method does not get into catch block in the same manner... I don't have idea what to do...

Comment: @Alexander If you have a question, you should post one. This is not the place to discuss an unrelated issue.